# Export table to pretty XLS/open document spreadsheet

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc, kable

What is the best way to export a table similar to this (retaining the formatting on the footnotes, bolding of titles etc) from R to an Excel XLS/open document format?

Is it possible with to neatly convert the HTML output in RMarkdown or export directly to Excel?

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
dt <- mtcars[1:5, 1:6]
kable(dt, align = "c") %>%
kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
footnote(general = "Here is a general comments of the table. ",
       number = c("Footnote 1; ", "Footnote 2; "),
       alphabet = c("Footnote A; ", "Footnote B; "),
       symbol = c("Footnote Symbol 1; ", "Footnote Symbol 2"),
       general_title = "General: ", number_title = "Type I: ",
       alphabet_title = "Type II: ", symbol_title = "Type III: ",
       footnote_as_chunk = T, title_format = c("italic", "underline")
       )
```

The output file will need to have multiple worksheets, e.g. the above + another for a title, and be white background filled.

basictabler / Rmarkdown hybrid might be an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: why not export to CSV?

Comment: Also need to be able to add group toggles ideally,would  that be possible via R?
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08CE98C4-0063-4D42-8AC7-8278C49E9AFF

Comment: How would specfiy the cell background when export to csv from in R?

Comment: yeah, then CSV doesn't work. But things like that you cannot do with pandoc anyway. It has no excel writer and doesn't do layout/styling/presentation, only content.

Comment: Could it achieved with https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/basictabler/vignettes/v07-excelexport.html

Comment: apparently yes, I don't know the r world that well..

Comment: It’s worth noting that this is unrelated to kable, pandoc and RMarkdown: these are technologies for creating formatted documents, true, but they exclusively deal with formatted *text* documents. Spreadsheets are fundamentally different, even if they include formatting.